# Adding a Subview on top of a Table View Controller in a specific location of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, subview

I have a TableViewController and would like to have a button over top of it in the bottom right corner, about 50x50 for size. I think the best way to do it is to load the button as a subview over the main TableViewController. But I can't figure out a way to do it.

How do I properly configure the xib file, the swift file to go with the xib, and then how to I create and locate the subview in my TableViewController.swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is probably to create a ViewController with your button and a TableView as subviews.

Comment: to make it more easy, create a UIViewController and add a cntainerView to it, wich embed the tableViewController. In your ViewController you can handle the ContainerView as normal UIView, and you can add subviews without any Problems. The TableViewController should concentrate on the tableView only, so it will be easy to reuse and understandable, and makes the controller cheaper :)